# Where is the best way to put the buttons? Left or right?

Tags: buttons

I am creating a panel but im not sure where is the correct place to put my buttons, either in the left or right, been trying to put it on the left but seems okay to look at, but not really sure.

[image]

Comment: What does "undo" do in this context? Seeing "undo" next to Save is not too common.

Comment: Example is if there is already a defaults on the fields. Either u have to undo it or save/update

Answer (score 1):

- LukeW has tested this for you: http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?571
- Take into account Fitts's law
- Be very careful with an Undo/Erase/Delete button. What kind of a user (and how many) would take the effort of filling out a webform, and then think "you know what, let's throw everything away". Those kinds of delete buttons are mostly clicked / ticked unintentionally. Bye bye user. Bye bye conversion. Don't put a delete button in the form.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Danny! Can you bring the content of that link forward? What's a summary of what LukeW wrote on that page?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it will be better from user's perspective. He can fill the form and tab his way to the "save" button.

[image]

And instead of "Undo" a "cancel" or "cancel changes" text would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

### **To the right**

It feels like you're mixing your design metaphors here.

If you want to align both your action buttons to the left, you should place the Save button on the left of the undo button, to continue the expected flow of the F-reading pattern (as per [Luke's heatmap referenced above](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?571)).

Therefore if you want the buttons in that order, then you should align them to the right. This is also because it's assumed that people naturally relate the "continue" item with the bottom-right of the page ([small sample size experiment](http://measuringuserexperience.com/SubmitCancel/)), just like with reading a book. You can see a discussion [here](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-ok-buttons-in-dialog-boxes-work-best-on-the-right/).

That example also uses the Z-reading pattern (more typical with short pages than long ones) to emphasis that the right-hand side if the natural end of the journey.

Not to throw a curveball, but with the balanced design of your page, have you thought about centring them?